# How to make a Trove crafting bench

Tags: trove

I just started playing Trove today and I was editing my plot. I removed my crafting bench thinking it would pop into my inventory so I could place it elsewhere but it didn't. I can't find a recipe or instructions for how to build or buy a new one.

Comment: I had the same problem.  I'm not entirely sure, but I think hitting the V key will bring up the menu that has the crafting table option.

Comment: @Batophobia Yeah, turns out that is exactly correct. F1 also brings up a little sidebar with keyboard shortcut hints, including that crafting menu.

Answer (score 4):

Like @Batophobia says, the V key brings up a crafting menu which has the crafting bench recipe.

Comment: @Chantola Plagiarism would involve not citing the source of the information. I'm not sure why Batophobia posted a comment instead of an answer but I thought it was appropriate to make it an answer since it correctly answered my question. Meta has a help topic [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) which explicitly states that it is okay to use another's content provided that they are correctly attributed. If I broke some rule, please provide a link to the appropriate page.

Comment: This is fine by me.  I posted a comment because I wasn't really sure if that was the correct key, going solely on memory.  I am happy that I could help answer the question.

Comment: @Batophobia Awesome! I appreciate the help, too.

Comment: I posted a similar question on meta a while ago, with more or less the [same](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9831/answering-a-question-using-someone-elses-comment) response.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays if you need new **Novice crafting bench** just press H - go to hub and there is a house where you can craft that one.

Answer (score 1):

You need 20 Shapestone in order to create a crafting table.

Once you have the required materials press "v" when you want to craft it.